# Can't hide page contents using PHP exit();

Tags: php, oop, exit

I have this function of adding a todo item:

```
function add() {
    //Access control
    $session=new Auth();
    $session->start();
    $access=new Access();
    $role=$_SESSION['userinfo']['role'];
    $action=2;
    $access->restrict($role,$action);
    $todo = $_POST['todo'];
    $this->set('title','Success - My Todo List App');
    $this->set('todo',$this->Item->query('insert into items (item_name) values (\''.mysql_real_escape_string($todo).'\')'));   
}
```

And normally add page which says that todo is successully added is like this:

```
<a class="big" href="../items/viewall">Todo successfully added. Click here to go back.</a>
```

But because I want to restrict access to a normal user to add a todo item, here is restrict function:

```
function restrict($role,$action){
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM permissions WHERE role_id='$role' AND action_id='$action'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($count>0){
        echo "<div class='warning_positive'>Access Granted</div>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<div class='warning_negative'>Access Denied</div>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

To deny access, It shows access denied and it doesn't add that todo item. But still it shows Todo successfully added. As you see I put that exit(); to make that string not seen but still it is see. What should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you *expecting* to `exit` there? the function?

Comment: I want exit() to hide the string `<a class="big" href="../items/viewall">Todo successfully added. Click here to go back.</a>` from displaying

Answer (score 1):

It because you are calling exit() within the function restrict() whose scope is ending with function scope.

Rather than showing error sting in the function restrict(), return number of rows.

Depending upon the returned count, either grant access or just show the error message.

This approach will reduce the lines of code.

Corrected code:

```
function restrict($role,$action){
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM permissions WHERE role_id='$role' AND action_id='$action'");
  $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
  return $count;
}

function add() {
  //Access control
  $session=new Auth();
  $session->start();
  $access=new Access();
  $role=$_SESSION['userinfo']['role'];
  $action=2;
  $access = $access->restrict($role,$action);
  if ($access > 0) {
    echo "<div class='warning_positive'>Access Granted</div>";
    $todo = $_POST['todo'];
    $this->set('title','Success - My Todo List App');
    $this->set('todo',$this->Item->query('insert into items (item_name) values (\''.mysql_real_escape_string($todo).'\')'));   
  }
  else {
        echo "<div class='warning_negative'>Access Denied</div>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below, should work.

```
function add() {
    //Access control
    $session=new Auth();
    $session->start();
    $access=new Access();
    $role=$_SESSION['userinfo']['role'];
    $action=2;
    if($access->restrict($role,$action)){
        echo "<div class='warning_positive'>Access Granted</div>";    
    }else{
        echo "<div class='warning_negative'>Access Denied</div>";
        exit();
    }
    $todo = $_POST['todo'];
    $this->set('title','Success - My Todo List App');
    $this->set('todo',$this->Item->query('insert into items (item_name) values (\''.mysql_real_escape_string($todo).'\')'));   
}


function restrict($role,$action){
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM permissions WHERE role_id='$role' AND action_id='$action'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($count>0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It still shows the string and also it adds the todo.

Comment: try to add `exit;` above  `$todo = $_POST['todo'];` line, just to debug purpose and check whether your code stops there or not.